# Get RoleName from a RoleGroup by UserID

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-8

I have a `RoleGroup` with some `Roles` in it. A user can only belong to one of these roles. How would I get the `RoleName` based on the `RoleGroup` which the user belongs to? Any ideas?

```
Dim roleGroupOmniProfiles = RoleController.GetRoleGroupByName(PortalSettings.Current.PortalId, "OmniProfiles")
```

Problem is here

```
Dim omniProfile = roleGroupOmniProfiles.Roles.Any(Function(role) oUser.UserID)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`roleGroupOmniProfiles` contains a collection of `KeyValuePair<string, RoleInfo>`, so you can loop them as shown below.

But I'm not sure you can get the `RoleName` from a `RoleGroup` by `UserID` since `UserID` has no direct link to `RoleGroup`. Shouldn't it be that you get all the Roles from a user based on `UserID` and check which `RoleGroup` the `Roles` belongs to, if any.

C#

```
var roleGroupOmniProfiles = RoleController.GetRoleGroupByName(PortalId, "OmniProfiles");

if (roleGroupOmniProfiles != null)
{
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, RoleInfo> role in roleGroupOmniProfiles.Roles)
    {
        Label1.Text += role.Key + " | " + role.Value.RoleName + "<br>";
    }
}
```

Or as one-liner

```
RoleInfo roleInfo = roleGroupOmniProfiles.Roles.Where(x => x.Value.RoleID == 15).FirstOrDefault().Value;
```

VB

```
If (Not (roleGroupOmniProfiles) Is Nothing) Then
    For Each role As KeyValuePair(Of String, RoleInfo) In roleGroupOmniProfiles.Roles
        Label1.Text += role.Key + " | " + role.Value.RoleName + "<br>"
    Next
End If
```

**UPDATE**

To check if a user belongs to a group you can use this

```
DotNetNuke.Entities.Users.UserInfo user = DotNetNuke.Entities.Users.UserController.GetUserByName("userName");
bool isInGroup = roleGroupOmniProfiles.Roles.Keys.Any(role => user.IsInRole(role));
```

Comment: Sorry, I've noticed that there's a bug. I have checked the vb.net version. The loop returns the last value from the roleGroup even though the user does not belong to any roles within the RoleGroup.

Comment: There is no bug since the VB and C# snippet don't do anything with users. They just loop Roles in a rolegroup collection. In the loop you could check `UserInfo.IsInRole` and return a bool if found, but that depends on your implementation... I can provide a complete solution if required

Comment: I think I might have messed up with the question. What I mean was to get the role which the user belongs to from a certain rolegroup. I did this based on your suggestion. Do you think it's the optimised solution or is there a faster way to achieve this via linq? `For Each role As KeyValuePair(Of String, RoleInfo) In oRoleGroupInfo.Roles
                If oUser.IsInRole(role.Value.RoleName) Then
                    oRoleAndPhoto.RoleName = role.Value.RoleName
                    oRoleAndPhoto.RolePhotoURL = role.Value.PhotoURL
                End If
            Next`